# How to programmatically intercept OSX (10.8) print command?

Tags: macos, printing, applescript

Basically, if I'd like to be able to handle a print job initialization command. Like hitting Cmd+P on a document or something. I'd like to be able to access the data being printed and programmatically handle it rather than through a GUI.

Thanks!

Comment: install a printer which simply prints to file, and grab that file?

Comment: Well OSX does have a PDF printer built in but you still have manually select it and click "Print".

Comment: Write your own printer driver/definition and set it to be the default? Similar to what MarcB mentioned, just much more complicated :)

Comment: There exists a printer driver called [CUPS-PDF](http://www.cups-pdf.de/) which saves print jobs to PDF files.  Select that as your default printer, and you could do this.  Now, whether this is sufficient to accomplish your goals, I can't say.

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly use the OSX automator to do what you need here.  It depends on what you want to get out of the printed document.  Automator allows you to create print plugins, which you can select from the system print dialog.  I see you mentioned already that you don't want to use the "PDF" print menu as is, but perhaps some value can be added with extra automation in a print plugin.  The plugin will create a .pdf of the printed documents, to which you can apply an automated sequence of actions.

1. Start /Applications/Automator
2. Under "Choose a type for your document:", choose "Print Plugin"
3. Then set up a sequence of actions you need to process your printed document.  For example, you might want to do "Extract PDF Text" or "PDF to Images".  Type "pdf" in the search field to see all the pdf-related actions available.
4. Save the automator workflow.  You will only be able to give it a name, but not save it as a file in an arbitrary path.
5. You can use the plugin by opening the system print dialog in any given application, then dropping down the "PDF" menu in the bottom left-hand corner.  You should see your plugin appear there.